# Why is pandas.read_json, modifying the value of long integers?

Tags: python, pandas, json-normalize

I don't know why the original content of **id_1** & **id_2** changes when I print it.

I have a json file named **test_data.json**

```
{
"objects":{
    "value":{
        "1298543947669573634":{
            "timestamp":"Wed Aug 26 08:52:57 +0000 2020",
            "id_1":"1298543947669573634",
            "id_2":"1298519559306190850"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
python test_data.py 
                  id_1                 id_2                 timestamp
0  1298543947669573632  1298519559306190848 2020-08-26 08:52:57+00:00
```

My code named **test_data.py** is

```
import pandas as pd
import json

file = "test_data.json"
with open (file, "r")  as f:
    all_data = json.loads(f.read()) 
data = pd.read_json(json.dumps(all_data['objects']['value']), orient='index')
data = data.reset_index(drop=True)
print(data.head())
```

How can I fix this, so the numeric values are interpreted correctly?

Comment: Using `python 3.7.4` & `pandas 0.25.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Using `python 3.8.5` and `pandas 1.1.1`

### Current Implementation

- First, the code reads the file in and converts it from a `str` type to a `dict`, with `json.loads`

```py
with open (file, "r")  as f:
    all_data = json.loads(f.read())
```

- Then `'value'` is converted back to a `str`

```py
json.dumps(all_data['objects']['value'])
```

- Using `orient='index'` sets the `keys` as columns headers and the `values` are in the rows.

  - The data is also converted to an `int` at this point, and the value changes.
  - I'm guessing that there's some floating point conversion issue in this step

    - [pandas issues: `read_json` reads large integers as strings incorrectly if `dtype` not explicitly mentioned #20608](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/20608)

```py
pd.read_json(json.dumps(all_data['objects']['value']), orient='index')
```

### Updated code

#### Option 1

- Use `pandas.DataFrame.from_dict` and then convert to numeric.

```py
file = "test_data.json"
with open (file, "r")  as f:
    all_data = json.loads(f.read()) 

# use .from_dict
data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(all_data['objects']['value'], orient='index')

# convert columns to numeric
data[['id_1', 'id_2']] = data[['id_1', 'id_2']].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')

data = data.reset_index(drop=True)

# display(data)
                        timestamp                 id_1                 id_2
0  Wed Aug 26 08:52:57 +0000 2020  1298543947669573634  1298519559306190850

print(data.info())
[out]:
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1 entries, 0 to 0
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column     Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------     --------------  ----- 
 0   timestamp  1 non-null      object
 1   id_1       1 non-null      int64 
 2   id_2       1 non-null      int64 
dtypes: int64(2), object(1)
memory usage: 152.0+ bytes
```

#### Option 2

- Use `pandas.json_normalize` and then convert columns to numeric.

```py
file = "test_data.json"
with open (file, "r")  as f:
    all_data = json.loads(f.read()) 

# read all_data into a dataframe
df = pd.json_normalize(all_data['objects']['value'])

# rename the columns
df.columns = [x.split('.')[1] for x in df.columns]

# convert to numeric
df[['id_1', 'id_2']] = df[['id_1', 'id_2']].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')

# display(df)
                        timestamp                 id_1                 id_2
0  Wed Aug 26 08:52:57 +0000 2020  1298543947669573634  1298519559306190850

print(df.info()
[out]:
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1 entries, 0 to 0
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column     Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------     --------------  ----- 
 0   timestamp  1 non-null      object
 1   id_1       1 non-null      int64 
 2   id_2       1 non-null      int64 
dtypes: int64(2), object(1)
memory usage: 152.0+ bytes
```

Comment: Thanks mate. Option1 using from_dict works perfectly. Even the .apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce') seems optional for my case. However I have used it too.

You saved me !

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by [issue 20608](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/20608) and still happens in the current 1.2.4 version of Pandas.

Here's my workaround, which is even slightly faster on my data than `read_json`:

```
def broken_load_json(path):
    """There's an open issue: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/20608
    about read_csv loading large integers incorrectly because it's converting
    from string to float to int, losing precision."""
    df = pd.read_json(pathlib.Path(path), orient='index')
    return df

def orjson_load_json(path):
    import orjson  # The builting json module would also work
    with open(path) as f:
        d = orjson.loads(f.read())
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')  # Builds the index from the dict's keys as strings, sadly
    # Fix the dtype of the index
    df = df.reset_index()
    df['index'] = df['index'].astype('int64')
    df = df.set_index('index')
    return df
```

Note that my answer preserves the values of the IDs, which are meaningful in my use case.